# how to use passwords with @ ! # chars in ansible shell ssh?

Tags: shell, ssh, ansible

I'm trying to run some simple checks via SSH on a bunch of remote servers. Nothing fancy.
One of the servers has a password like `mY*test@2PAss!01lZ#` in my inventory `.yml` file.

For this particular server I'm getting:

```
SRV1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Invalid/incorrect password: Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/redacted/.ssh/known_hosts).\r\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n* WARNING                                                                    *\n* You are accessing a secured system and your actions will be logged along   *\n* with identifying information. Disconnect immediately if you are not an     *\n* authorized user of this system.                                            *\n------------------------------------------------------------------------------\nPermission denied, please try again.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

None of the things I've tried work:

1. escaping `mY*test\@2PAss\!01lZ\#` or any other combinations of the `*`, `@`, `!`, `#` chars
2. using ansible vault
3. using `ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ i_pass | regex_escape() }}"`
4. single/double quotes

I'm out of ideas.

Anybody had similar problems?

INFO:

- ansible 2.9.6
- `python version = 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) [GCC 9.3.0]`
- connecting from Ubuntu to a RHEL box
- similar connection to another RHEL box with a password which doesn't have such "special" chars works fine
- I can't define public/private keys or change the password. The destination box is installed and configured by another team, and then the box is shared between multiple other teams.

Comment: It works for me in Ubuntu 20.4 and FreeBSD 12.0 (no RH atm). No escape/quoting is needed "ansible_ssh_pass: mY*test@2PAss!01lZ#". Make sure the problem is not [sshpass](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_bsd.html#connecting-to-bsd-nodes). Try "ansible_connection: paramiko".

Comment: FWIW, there is some strange password caching in Ansible usage of sshpass. A changed password in the inventory doesn't take effect immediately.

Comment: Tried with ```paramiko```, getting: ```SRV1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to authenticate: Authentication failed.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: And BTW, I have tried several times direct ssh to the nodes with copy paste of the password from the inventory file, and it works.

Comment: Oh man, actually this is silly. I have misstyped the last number of the host IP :) Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

it is easier to use public-key-authentication, so you do not need any password.

About the special characters, i made a test:

```
ansible localhost -m command -a "echo '{{ a }}'" -e '{"a": "mY*test@2PAss!01lZ#"}'
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
mY*test@2PAss!01lZ#
```

So it is not a generell problem.